# Xcode: can't run test target

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm building a static library for iOS, and implemented the first unit test in the test target.
However, when I run the tests with `Command+U` (simulator), the debugger halts on some ASM stack trace with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` before even a test class is executed.

In the thread view the step before is

```
#15 0x8feb02ef in dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*) ()
```

The ASM stack trace is as following (assume it doesn't help much):

```
0x0:  into   
0x1:  cli    
0x2:  inl    %dx                      
0x3:  incb   (%edi)
0x5:  addb   %al, (%eax)
0x7:  addb   %al, (%ebx)
0x9:  addb   %al, (%eax)
0xb:  addb   %al, (%edx)
0xd:  addb   %al, (%eax)
0xf:  addb   %dl, (%eax)
0x11:  addb   %al, (%eax)
0x13:  addb   %cl, %al
0x15:  orb    %al, (%eax)
0x17:  addb   %al, 16842752(%ebp)
0x1d:  addb   %al, (%eax)
```

Any gotchas I should be aware of testing a static lib? Anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 4.3 uses `LLDB` by default. Switched to `GDB` and it shows me the error.

I guess `LLDB` isn't as mature as Apple thought...